# GCD hangs in menu bar app

Tags: cocoa, swift3

I have a menu bar app, which out of nowhere (no code changes) stopped working. Oddly the app continues to execute once I select it, or if I use any of the system keys (volume, brightness, iTunes, etc...). My code uses GCD to manage behavior. Is there a way to debug this and see what's going on behind the scenes? My confusion is why using the system keys (which pop up a window to show volume level, brightness level) makes my software continue execution?

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() { doSomething() }

func doSomething() {
    //run a bunch of things in a background process
    //so far works ok

    let fooFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100)

    print("tag1") //this prints just fine

    DispqtchQueue.main.sync() {
        print("tag2") //this doesn't print and doesn't execute until I click on the app or use the volume keys.
        //run code to update UI works fine once I use volume keys (no idea why)

        self.window.frame = fooFrame
    }
}
```

Also I am not getting any messages or exceptions raised. Just the app freezes. I have also noticed that if I have multiple displays and activate a second display, where the menu bar activates, then my process continues again and everything is normal.

Comment: (1) I'm giving you the part of the code that I think matters. There's a function which runs in async and trying to run some block in sync hangs. (2) calling async hangs in the exact same spot.

Comment: "I'm giving you the part of the code that I think matters" I know that. What I'm saying is that you're wrong about that. If you knew what mattered you'd have solved your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `AnyQue.sync` from the the same queue (`AnyQueue`) causes a deadlock, as the calling task is waiting for the called one. But the called one will start after the calling one finished.

As written by matt, using `async` fixes the issue. This code:

```
func doSomething() {
    print("tag1")
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        print("tag2")
    }
}

DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    doSomething()
}
```

prints:

```
tag1
tag2
```

Comment: I have tried async and it's still the same issue. Also the process continues (regardless of sync vs async) after hitting any of the system keys. That's the part that's confusing to me.

Comment: Does my sample not print `tag2` on your system or does your frame update  `self.window.frame = fooFrame` not work?

Comment: It doesn't print tag2. It works in playground but when the app is changed to type UIElement it seems to stop working. Something about it being a menu item app. I'm going to have to research this some more.

Comment: Please update the question how you "changed to type UIElement".

Comment: Through info.plist. The app is always UIElement. I am not dynamically changing it or anything.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out, I had a CFRunLoop running which needed to be stopped and then everything seems to work fine now. Also additionally, the entire process was running as a background dispatch process, that's why using sync worked.